# Designing DAL in .NET to be "data-source independent" and not just "database independent"?

Tags: .net, data-access-layer

How to design such flexible DAL (specifically in .NET) ?

What interfaces .NET provides and what should be done on my own ?

Its a greenfield project starting with SQL Server as data source but in future, parts of it will move to different NoSQL type of datastores.

Also, we may need to experiment with lot of different datastores (like some data may have to go with Cassandra, some with RDBMS, some to other DHT etc.)

Therefore easily switchable access layer will be needed. All i know right now is the 'data' and 'operations needed on that data'.

Comment: This kind of approach is a major source of project failure.

Comment: Hans, can you elaborate a little ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply: you do not. Ths is not so much about technology, but about totally different behavioral characteristics between different stores.

For example, SQL really shines in queries, and any decent DAL will expose those in a dynamic fashion (i..e no "GetCustomerById" function).

Replacing this with a XML File will be horrific and put a lot of stress on the DAL side - you need to reimplement a very powerfull search semantics without the proper disc structures to speed it up.

Most NoSQL data stores seriously ysuck once you get used to the proper relational theorem. They are not compareable in behavior and functionality, and as such a DAL can not abstract this away in a nontrivial project.

Comment: Well, isnt it that we want to abstract away the behavioral or any other specifics by DAL ? If my Business logic needs say a URL filter, then it should be transparent to whether the (URL, IsSeen) is stored as DB table or as KVP in some NoSQL. Ofcourse here XML wont make sense. So to evaluate which datastore forms most efficient for a particular purpose, my DAL should be able to switch to another datastore with minimal efforts. Isnt it what we can expect from DAL ?

Comment: Yes and no. YOu can not abstract away significant behavrioal differences. If "find url by pattern match" takes 1s second on a sql database, 1 hour on xml, how you want to abstract that away? NICEW theory, totally unusable in practice. Also things like transaction behavior et are somethimes REALLY HARD (!) to abstract away. A DAL is not to allow reaplcement of data store technologies.

Comment: It allows sometimes efficeent replacement of technology implementations (sql server vs. oracle, both relational databases). It is mostly there to reduce redundant code and make things maintainable and testable.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's a bit of a fluffy question, but you might get some ideas if you look at something like NHibernate. I'm not suggesting you adopt it (or don't adopt it) but you'll see how a mature framework like that separates repository specifics from the code.

Also, take a look at how the framework defines connections, commands, etc for SQL Server. There's a SqlConnection which implements IDbConnection. If your code then operates on IDbConnection you are free to switch to say an oracle connection (well in theory).