# is there a way to include sql plugins to my c#application

Tags: c#, mysql

i developed `C#` application for windows the back end is `mysql` database but the problem is, if i want to run it in different computer it requires `mysql` server  software or other wise it cant open the data base. is there any way to add plugins to the s `C#` application or adding open source software to my installation package to run the database file. please note i'm new to `C#` this is for education purpose sorry for if my questions asking method is not professional.

Front end : `visual studio 2013`
Back End : `Mysql server 2008`

Comment: What exactly are you using? an SDK? an executable? Also, what are you trying to accomplish? There are plenty of database implementations that are portable.

Comment: thank u for answering im using visual studio 2013 and sql server 2008 a mdf database file and can show me the right direction

Comment: What kind of application? Windows Forms, WPF, what? If you need a local database (each user has his/her own database) then you could look into `SQLite`. SQLite is an embedded database, all the stuff needed to use it can be downloaded from Nuget. The actual database is just a file on disc.

Comment: yeah it is a windows form application and if i use sqlite i have to change the coding right

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i got your question right but i assume it a general Data Access Layer strategy question.

If you "bind" your application with mySQL or any other db then that's it.

Depending on the size of the application you could use open source db like [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) It is a one file db that can be stored with your application.

If you really want to be able to use your software with many underlying DBs then you have alot of job.

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592226/designing-dal-in-net-to-be-data-source-independent-and-not-just-database-ind) question in SO debates that maybe it is not a good idea or at least it is a partially good idea. Partially means that you could abstract basic db behavior to be db independent but you will not get rid off the dependencies 100%

Another good approach would be to use an ORM. Either a micro ORM like [dapper](https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEkQFjACahUKEwjp7N2O0u7HAhVHMBoKHWZdA3Y&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FStackExchange%2Fdapper-dot-net&usg=AFQjCNHKnB9LSMdSIXWOV5e5ISSSwyivBQ&sig2=7u7KoQOrYAHMjX-Y77LusQ) or afull ORM like [Nhibernate](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-features.html)

ORMs let you do just that. You can use an OleDb provider and have access to many underlying sources at a cost of course of not using 100% the native capabilities of the DB....